# How to Insert a Div in a Flexbox Brick Wall Without Breaking the Nth-Child Logic?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

I want to inject randomly (with jquery) divs of the full width `bigbrick` class. What happens now is that after a `.bigbrick` div is inserted, all of the nth-child logic breaks. How can I add a `bigbrick` without breaking everything above it?

There are a few duplicate questions of how to force the flexbox to break for the div, but none talk about the consequences with elements coming after.

The example below is what I have now to illustrate. Everything above the `bigbrick` doesn't format correctly.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;

}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  min-width:1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap-reverse {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.flex-container li {
  background: brown;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bigbrick {
  background: gold!important;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 1200px!important;
  height: 240px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block!important;

}

.flex-container li:nth-child(9n),
.flex-container li:nth-child(9n+5) {
  width: 150px;
}

.flex-container {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}

.flex-container li:before {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
  content: counter(my-counter);
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap-reverse">

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li> </li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="bigbrick">Big Brick</div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's worth note that a div can't be a direct child of a list. the code is in fact invalid.

Comment: you shouldn't add div in list item.. it should be inside li > div

Comment: I guess I am mistaken in my approach. Is there a good way to randomly insert a full width child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `li` to use `span` instead then consider `nth-of-type` and you won't affect the logic when adding a `div` (which is another type of element).

*The change of `li` to `span` is to make your code valid.*

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  min-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap-reverse {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.flex-container span {
  background: brown;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bigbrick {
  background: gold!important;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 1200px!important;
  height: 240px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block!important;
}

.flex-container span:nth-of-type(9n),
.flex-container span:nth-of-type(9n+5) {
  width: 150px;
}

.flex-container {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}

.flex-container span:before {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
  content: counter(my-counter);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container wrap-reverse">

  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span> </span>
  <span></span>
  <div class="bigbrick">Big Brick</div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried span for the bigbrick, but I didn't know I could change the list to span. I'm a 90s tables guy, so all of this flexbox stuff is blowing my mind. Very cool. [Note: I upvoted and will select as answer. My upvotes not public since <15 on the main stack.]